# Put php into a function to shortcut

Tags: php, wordpress

New to php, but I've learned how it works (I mean, I can write php and do the things in the YouTube tutorials). I'm having difficulty applying it to actual use though:

I want to shorten the amount of php I need to put on *frontpage.php* (WordPress, but I hear this question is not a WordPress question; just a php one).

I'm going to call the same php many times to display 1 post each time, just changing the category to display in the php - so, now I have:

```
lots of php cat=33 lots of php
```

I want to make a function so that on my frontpage.php, I just need to write:

```
whatever cat=33 whatever
```

or just

```
whatever 33
```

If it helps to have my code, it is (this has tag, but I use both tag and cat here and there):

```
<?php
            $args=array(
              'tag' => 'feature-left',
              'showposts'=>1,
              'caller_get_posts'=>1
            );
            $my_query = new WP_Query($args);
                $offset = 3;
            if( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
            while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>
                <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>" itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="http://schema.org/BlogPosting" itemprop="blogPost">
                  <h4><?php the_excerpt(); ?> </h4>         
                </a>
                 <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" >
               <div class="front-first-article-title" itemprop="headline"><h2 style="color:#00589C; margin-bottom:5px;"><b><?php the_title(); ?></b></h2>
                </div>
                <?php
                endwhile;
                } //if ($my_query)
                    wp_reset_query();  // Restore global post data stomped by the_post().
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your theme folder, find your functions.php file.

In that file, place this code (from your question) into a function, like so:

```
function my_custom_loop($category) {
        $args=array(
          'tag'                 => 'feature-left',
          // showposts has been replaced, use 'posts_per_page' instead
          // 'showposts'        =>1,
          'posts_per_page'      => 1,
          // this has been replaced, use 'ignore_sticky_posts'
          // 'caller_get_posts' => 1,
          'ignore_sticky_posts' => true,
          'cat'                 => $category
        );

        $my_query = new WP_Query($args);
        $offset = 3;
        if( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
            while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>
                <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>" itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="http://schema.org/BlogPosting" itemprop="blogPost">
                     <h4><?php the_excerpt(); ?> </h4>         
                 </a>
                 <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" >
                <div class="front-first-article-title" itemprop="headline"><h2 style="color:#00589C; margin-bottom:5px;"><b><?php the_title(); ?></b></h2>
                </div>
            <?php
            endwhile;
        } //if ($my_query)

        wp_reset_query();  // Restore global post data stomped by the_post().
}
```

Now, in your home page file, you can drop in `my_custom_loop(33)` to have it output your custom post loop.

**NOTE**
There's a few issues with your HTML inside your loop.  You shouldn't put `<div>` or `<h2>` or `<h4>` elements inside of an `<a>` tag.  Also, your `<a>` tag is not getting closed properly.  Lastly, I'd suggest using classes / CSS rather than inline styles on your `<h2>`, as it's going to be output to the screen many times, and it's sorta silly to output the exact same inline CSS a bunch of times.

**EDIT**
Per your recent comments, yes, you could make the function also handle tags, and have the "number" be dynamic.  Note that there are a variety of approaches to this sort of issue, but the most direct (given your existing function) would be something like so:

```
/* Note the "default values" for $tag and $offset. 
 * You can call this function in many ways: 
 * my_custom_loop(33); just get the categories, with an offset of 3
 * my_custom_loop(33, NULL, 5); get the categories, offset of 5
 * my_custom_loop(NULL, 'feature-left'); get the tags, offset of 3
 * my_custom_loop(NULL, 'feature-left', 5); get the tags, offset of 5
 */
function my_custom_loop($category, $tag = NULL, $offset = 3) {
        $args=array(
          // showposts has been replaced, use 'posts_per_page' instead
          // 'showposts'        =>1,
          'posts_per_page'      => 1,
          // this has been replaced, use 'ignore_sticky_posts'
          // 'caller_get_posts' => 1,
          'ignore_sticky_posts' => true,
        );

        if ($category) {
          $args['cat'] = $category;
        }

        if ($tag) {
          $args['tag'] = 'feature-left';
        }

        $my_query = new WP_Query($args);
        // ... rest of function to output loop 
 }
```

Comment: Thanks! Makes total sense. Just what I was hoping for.

Comment: Would it be possible to see how I could use this single function for either tag or cat, and include the offset as a variable, so that I could write on the page, "my_custom_loop(33, [offset]2)" OR my_custom_loop('tagname', 4"?

Comment: Yes, you could do both.  I will improve the answer to reflect this request.

Comment: That's cool code. Thanks, although I have a feeling there's going to be a ton of WordPress users who are going to be able to use this particular piece of code (actually, I just modified the tag code slightly so it can be universal like the category). Only thing is the offset doesn't seem to work for me. I can display any category or tag with your code, but any offset entered still displays the most recent post

Comment: Just adjusted it. I just did the same thing you did with category for tag and offset, and all three can be controlled as the coder wants from the calls you showed.

Answer (score 1):

if you dont want your functions to be crowded you can create folder lets call it `templates/parts/`
for each part you want to reuse put inside one `.PHP` file .

then any where you need this block you call it

```
<?php include(locate_template( 'templates/parts/slider-box.php' ));?>
```

this is better from design prospective . for example the main page for one website I am building looks like this

```
        <?php $catNum = 23; ?>
        <?php include(locate_template( 'templates/parts/slider-box.php' ));?>
        <?php include(locate_template( 'templates/parts/ads3.php' ));?>
        <?php $catNum = 2; ?>
        <?php include(locate_template( 'templates/parts/catBlox-main.php' ));?>
        <?php $catNum = 4; ?>
        <?php include(locate_template( 'templates/parts/catBlox-main.php' ));?>
        <?php $catNum = 3; ?>
        <?php include(locate_template( 'templates/parts/catBlox-main.php' ));?>
```

and I have all the files for each parts in one folder I can move them to other project or when there is problem it easer to go to file other than go to function in 1 big function.php

Comment: Thanks, J.Tural, that's a very helpful tip for me. I'm pretty sure I'll use that. Do you also know how to delay loading these things until after the dom. It seems like it'd be nice to store some elements outside, like you show here, and then have them load after the initial load

Comment: no problem my frind ... about your other Q? I dont know exactly you are looking for ajax loading ... I suggest you add other Question I will be interested to see the way its good idea .

Comment: Yes, I think you're right that it should probably be separate